# How to install this extension in Octave (pcbmodelgen for openEMS)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, installation, octave

I am not understanding how to install this extension called [pcbmodelgen](https://github.com/jcyrax/pcbmodelgen?fbclid=IwAR0u3fRTQhEKtEUyVSPMohlgHNSZYnVdVSn3cQQ0TTRS3QPOq7fFLjjaE88), it is for [openEMS](http://openems.de/index.php/OpenEMS?fbclid=IwAR3Pn1ZmbB1Q_yvo8IHJ-is7JkCsqIXQFitLUFx5kQQ4rnGNRLBfvt7G3tI) EM simulation software which runs in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index). I am using Windows 10, I already have openEMS up and running and have been doing simulations with no problem and can view the 3D models on [appCSXCAD](http://openems.de/index.php/AppCSXCAD.html), so all this is installed correctly I assume.

So going down the list of instructions on [GitHub](https://github.com/jcyrax/pcbmodelgen?fbclid=IwAR0u3fRTQhEKtEUyVSPMohlgHNSZYnVdVSn3cQQ0TTRS3QPOq7fFLjjaE88)…

I believe all this is for Linux only, correct me if I'm wrong:

> ### **Dependencies**
>
> **Usage dependencies**
>
> -AppCSXCAD
>
> -OpenEMS
>
> **Build dependencies**
>
> 1. TinyXML2 https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2 (packages available)
> 2. TCLAP http://tclap.sourceforge.net/ (packages available)
>
> ### **Build**
>
> **Linux**
>
> Download package and execute from root:
>
> ```
> # Dependencies sudo apt-get install libtinyxml2-dev libtclap-dev
>  
> # Build and install  
> mkdir build 
> cd build 
> cmake ../ 
> make 
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> **Usage**
>
> OpenEMS should be installed and the octave paths should be configured
> in ~/.octaverc as in:
>
> ```
> addpath('/usr/share/octave/packages/openems-0.0.35/')
> addpath('/usr/local/share/CSXCAD/matlab/')
> ```

The folder locations on Windows do not exist for the two addpaths listed above. Here’s the addpath I use for Windows, both the AppCSXCAD and openEMS exe files are in that folder, and install instructions are from [here](http://openems.de/index.php/OpenEMS). I put the lines in "octaverc" file at `C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.1.0\mingw64\share\octave\6.1.0\m\startup`:

```
addpath('D:/openEMS/matlab');
```

And is the Ubuntu console app for Windows supposed to be this running these commands? I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu or Linux.

> The tool can be used as in:
>
> ```
> # Example
> pcbmodelgen -p board.kicad_pcb -c pcbmodelgen.json
>
> # Extra help
> pcbmodelgen -h
> ```
>
> There are some examples in the example directory. Inside each example
> folder has a makefile to run the example.
>
> ```
> # To run everything just type
> make
>
> # To generate the mesh of the Kicad's PCB
> make run
>
> # To simulate the generated mesh with openEMS
> make sim
>
> # To clean the generated files
> make clean
> ```
>
> These steps will show model using the AppCSXCAD and after exit from
> its 3D viewer, the next step is to run the simulation with openEMS and
> present results.

Then there's this:

> **Windows users:**
>
> On Windows 10 it has been tested with the WLS Linux Ubuntu App,
> downloaded from Microsoft Store. The AppCSXCAD and the openEMS must be
> available on PATH environment variable so pcbgenmod can find required
> tools.

Here's my PATH variables and both the AppCSXCAD and openEMS exe files are in the `C:\openEMS` folder:

[image]

So looking at all this I'm not sure where the actual installation of pcbmodelgen comes in. I ran this line in the Ubuntu console and it says command not found:

```
wdbwdb1@DESKTOP-V94BUKT:~$ pcbmodelgen -p board.kicad_pcb -c pcbmodelgen.json
```

RESULT:

```
pcbmodelgen: command not found
```

Am I supposed to download any of the files from GitHub and store them anywhere or run something from that folder or something? There are no instructions on that anywhere and I can't find anything else as far as how to install on Windows. I'm sure I need to do something with the files but I don't know what to do.  If someone could please assist I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `pcbmodelgen -p board.kicad_pcb -c pcbmodelgen.json` you missed out the `pcbmodelgen ` command and tried to run only the command arguments

Comment: I actually typed that wrong, I did try the full command and this is the result:


wdbwdb1@DESKTOP-V94BUKT:~$ pcbmodelgen -p board.kicad_pcb -c pcbmodelgen.json
 
RESULT: pcbmodelgen: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: cool tool! But also, leaving only about two lines for Windows users is almost malevolent. The steps below led me to success:

1. activate the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature (control panel\all control panel items\programs and features) and install (f.e.) the Ubuntu app from the microsoft store.

The following steps are to be performed from the ubuntu command line.

2. install updates:
   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. install dependencies:
   `sudo apt-get install libtinyxml2-dev libtclap-dev`
4. install cmake:
   `sudo apt install cmake`
5. install CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
   `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
6. install pcbmodelgen:

- `mkdir build`
- `cd build`
- `cmake /mnt/...` (path to the pcbmodelgen-master folder, slash as separator,  drive letter without colon)
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

And that's it. For running pcbmodelgen you just have to go to the folder that contains the .kicad_pcb
`cd /mnt/...` and start it from there.
When you try out the examples in the master folder you will see that there is always a "Makefile" for the commands, a "pcbmodelgen.json" for the configs and a "simulation_script.m". For me it turned out to be useful, to copy, paste and adjust these files for my own pcbs. In the Makefile you will find a simulation command as well, that logically won't work if octave and openEMS are installed on Windows. So you may delete or uncomment it. Running the program from the script (`make`) generates one "kicad_pcb_model.m" and one "kicad_pcb_mesh.m" file. From now on you can continue using the "simulation_script.m" under Windows.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Addition: Instead of deleting the sim command in the makefile you can replace the line `octave --silent --persist simulation_script.m` with `wscript.exe "...your-octave-path-including...\octave.vbs" --silent --persist --gui simulation_script.m`,
where everything after .exe is to be entered in Windows Style (Colon,Backslashes etc.). That should save some mouse pushing.